# Installing steinmetz.sty

Tags: packages

I'm trying to use steinmetz.sty package in **texmaker** (texlive installed underneath), in a **debian system** (updated to date july 2018).

I've downloaded the package from homepage (https://ctan.org/pkg/steinmetz) generated .sty file.

Here is the question, **where I'm supposed to put it in order my editor to include it in compilation process?**

I've found directory `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex` with a bunch of directories that I've concluded are supposed to contain the corresponding .sty file, after exploring all the directories included here.

So I created a new one called "steinmetz" and copy "steinmetz.sty" in it  without success. To test it, I stopped and re-start textmamker, and, again, no compilation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try `apt install texlive-science`?

Answer (score 2):

I installed `texlive-science` and now I have a new directory:

`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/`

containing four packages, among them I have `steinmetz.sty`.

I've also verified that this file and the one I used to try are the same (using `diff`) So, there must be a logic about directory names and placing policy I can't figure out now. But that's another issue.